# Extension Sobolev functions across of lower dimensional subset

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde

This question may be well-known to experts, but I am trying to get myself a rigorous proof. Consider open set $\Omega=B^n_1(0)\setminus B_1^k(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If function $u$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$, can we make it  in $H^1(B_1^n(0))$ by arbitrarily adding value on $B_1^k(0)$. I think this problem can be similarly stated in a more general setting instead of balls.

What I have tried: take any $f\in C_c^\infty(B_1^n)$ and define a cutoff function $\varphi_\epsilon$ that is 1 when distance r from $B_1^k$ is bigger than $\epsilon$ and decreasing in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood with derivative smaller than $1/\epsilon$, then
$$-\int_{B^n_1} (\varphi_\epsilon f)_iu=\int_{B^n_1}(\varphi_\epsilon f)u_i.$$
Then I want to use the DCT to take the limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$

Two questions: (1) On the RHS: it seems that we need $u_i$ is bounded, but we don't have this. Maybe we can use that $\int_\Omega u_i^2$ is bounded, $u_i$ is integrable by holder inequality? However, it is not even defined on $B_1^k$, can we just assume it is defined because we are using integration here?

(2) The LHS becomes $-\int_{B_1^n}(\varphi_\epsilon)_ifu-\int_{B^n_1}\varphi_\epsilon f_iu$. In terms of the second term, I have the same question as above. Regarding the first term, this is the main question I have:
$$|\int_{B_1^n}(\varphi_\epsilon)_ifu|\leq \|u\|_{L^2}\frac{C}{\epsilon^2}\times Volume(\epsilon-Neighborhood)\leq C \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\epsilon^{n-k}=C\epsilon^{n-k-2}$$
where I used Holder inequality in the first inequality. That means codimension $n-k$ must be strictly bigger than 2 so that we can make it vanish. Does that sound correct? Because in my intuition codimension 2 should be fine. I think if $u$ is bounded in the neighborhood of that subset, it will give what I want, however, we don't have that, right?

Maybe more general question is: what is the difference between $H^1(K\setminus C)$ and $H^1(K)$ if $K$ is a bounded domain and $C$ is a subset.

Maybe what I have done doesn't make any sense. If someone can answer my questions or direct me to some related references, it will be very much appreciated.